# Auto-complete input2 with the value from input1

Tags: javascript, php, html

On page 1.html I have this form:

```
<form id="my_form" action="2.html">
<input type="text" id="input1" value="" />   
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

After the user presses the button he is redirected to 2.html. On this page I have this input:

```
<input type="text" id="input2" value="" />
```

How can I get `input2` **"auto-completed"** with the value inserted by the user in `input1` ?

Tried this:

Changed 2.html to 2.php and `<input type="text" id="input2" value="" />` to `<input type="text" id="input2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input1'])?>" />` - **no luck**

Different approaches using sessionStorage - **no luck**.

I must be missing something simple, please help...

Comment: Try using the 'name' instead of the 'id' attribute for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script is not working is because `#input1` is missing `name` attribute .. try changing html of `#input1` to this :

```
<input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />
```

Also, you were not declaring any method on form, by default if the method is not declared then it is set as `GET`. As you are getting values on second page by `POST`, declare form method to `POST`.

So, the html of form will be:

```
<form id="my_form" action="2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />   
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can't manage to make it work. input2 in the php file just shows the litteral value <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input1'])?>

Comment: what is the type of that file ? And also, do you have `apache` installed ?

Comment: @ Syed Qarib - Thank you! Idiot me, was testing it outside apache!! Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

In the form on page 1.html you didn't provide a submission method. Try changing it to

```
<form id="my_form" action="2.html method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" value="" />   
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can't manage to make it work. input2 in the php file just shows the litteral value <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input1'])?>

Comment: if the second file 2.html, change it to 2.php